# Java MimeMessage add text to existing mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

In our system we have mailmessages saved and a function where we can forward these messages.
I know want to be able to add text to the top of the message when we forward it.
This has proven to be surprisingly difficult.

Some of the code.

```
private void addMessageStartOfMail(MimeMessage mail, String forwardMailBody) throws Exception{
    Object content = mail.getContent();     
    if (content.getClass().isAssignableFrom(MimeMultipart.class)) {
        MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) content;
        for (int i = 0; i < mimeMultipart.getCount(); i++) {
            BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);

             if (bodyPart.getContentType().startsWith("text/plain")) {
                 String cnt = forwardMailBody;
                  cnt = MailUtil.toPlainText(cnt);
                  cnt = cnt + (String)bodyPart.getContent();                     
                 bodyPart.setContent(cnt, bodyPart.getContentType());
             }
  ......
```

This works but unfortunatelly not all mails are text/plain, some are text/html and worse, some are multipart which is a total mess.

The trouble code

```
    }else if(bodyPart.getContentType().startsWith("multipart")) {
Multipart mp = (Multipart) bodyPart.getContent();
int count = mp.getCount();
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
     BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(j);                       
        if (bp.getContentType().startsWith("text/html")) {
            String cnt = form.getForwardMailBody();
            cnt = cnt + (String)bp.getContent();
            bp.setContent(cnt,  bp.getContentType());
            ....
```

For some reason this turns the contenttype from html to plain which makes the original message a mess.

I feel there must be a smarter way to this.
Can I somehow add a simple bodypart to beginning of a Mimemessage or something.
Any advice?

After VGRs answer I made a new attempt.

```
    private void addMessageStartOfMail(MimeMessage mail, String forwardMailBody) throws Exception{
    Object content = mail.getContent();     
    if (content.getClass().isAssignableFrom(MimeMultipart.class)) {
        MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) content;
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText("Test");       
        mimeMultipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart, 0);
    }

}
```

Obviously much cleaner but how do I add the new bodypart. I want it at top of the mail but without overwriting the original mail, which this solution did.

Comment: Did you happen to look at the [documentation for Multipart](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/Multipart.html)?  The second method is an `addBodyPart` method which takes an insertion index.

Comment: You are right and this must be the way to go, for some reason I thought I couldn't just instantiate a new Bodypart but if apparently you can if you name it MimeBodyPart.

Comment: That's because [BodyPart is an abstract class](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/BodyPart.html) whereas [MimeBodyPart is not](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html).  Again, the documentation will tell you all of this;  there's no need to guess.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaMail FAQ describes two ways to [forward a message](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#forward).

The simplest way is to create a new message and attach the original message as an attachment.

If instead you want to forward the original message "inline", you need to construct a new body for the message based on the body from the original message.  The JavaMail FAQ contains [code for finding the main message body](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#mainbody).  Preserving the original structure of the message with the attachments and so on is much more difficult, especially when you consider all the possible cases of multipart/related, multipart/alternative, etc.

The technique described in the comments above of inserting a new MimeBodyPart into the original message will work in some cases, but it will still be a challenge to find out where exactly to insert it, and the end result may not display as you would like.

Comment: OK, I have to say I am strugling with this.
The code I found there is:
MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
mbp.setContent(forwardedMsg, "message/rfc822");
mp.addPart(mbp);
What type of object is "mp" in this example and what is "forwardedMsg"? Is it  the old message or the message I want added at start?

Comment: "mp" is a Multipart object that will be the content of the new message you're creating.  That Multipart object should also contain whatever content you want to provide when forwarding the message. "forwardedMsg" is the original MimeMessage object that you're forwarding.

Comment: This is not going well for me. I am starting to feel like an idiot.
Nothing I test works for all mails, if I change the mail with setText, mails with attacments looses there attachment and so on.
If anyone finds a working example where someone adds a String to an existing MimeMessage somehow I would be very grateful, I will probably check here from time to time. For now however I must admit defeat.

Comment: I told you it was going to be difficult!  :-)  To have any hope of success you really need to understand how MIME works and all the possible MIME types and structures for email.